# How to increase max number of connections to Whois server in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, connection

I'm querying a Whois server for information on a lot of domains.  Here is my request code:

```
checkDomain (domain, callback) ->
    client = net.connect {port: 43, host: 'whois.examplenic.com'}, ->
        client.write domain + '.com' + '\r\n'

        client.on 'data', (data) ->
            ... do something with data ...
```

I first had some code that fired `checkDomain` sequentially.  Then I decided to try 2 at a time and that doubled performance.  But after 4, performance didn't increase at all.  Which means that the number of connections is limited to 4 either by Node or the Whois server.  Is there a way I can tell?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure access to whois servers are rate limited, as pointed out [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/176415/is-there-a-rate-limit-or-any-sort-of-limit-to-calling-whois-in-ubuntu-10-04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try your code with different Whois servers. If the performance differs, that would point to a server-dependent bottleneck; if it is the same, that would point to a Node bottleneck. I *very* much doubt Node would have any problem with just 4 concurrent connections, so it is much more likely you're seeing a server-dependent bottleneck; but you asked for a way to tell so here you go.

Comment: There is a mechanism called [HTTP Agents](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent), which limits the number of concurrent requests, but as its name indicates, it only concerns HTTP requests. I agree with @lanzz that the bottleneck is probably not on node's side.